# select and trap INT shows different behavior in case of command substitution in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

Normally, when `INT` is trapped, `select` will not let `shell` respond immediately with `Ctr-C` signal. When this script is run and then user presses `Ctr-C`, nothing happens. User has to press `RETURN`, types something then presses `RETURN` again to see `trap` works.

```sh
trap 'echo INT signal TRAPPED; exit 0' INT

a=(A B C)

function choose_item ()
{
PS3="Choose an item in the preceding list: "
select n in ${a[*]}; do
  echo "You choose $n"
  return 0
done
}

choose_item
#$(choose_item)
```

However, when we:

1. comment the line `choose_item`
2. uncomment the line `$(choose_item)`
3. run the script
4. presses Ctr-C,

the script terminates immediately and shows that trap works.
So what is the role of `command substitution`?

Answer (score 0):

With `$(choose_item)` you start another process. The commandline is replaced by the stdout of that process.

```
my_echo() {
   echo "echo again"
}
my_echo
$(my_echo)
```

returns
echo again
again
The second call has returned the command `echo again`. You can see the normal output with `echo "$(my_echo)"`.
The `select` is a systemcall that doesn't like to be killed, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513466/57293. With `choose_item` you send a signal to the `select`-call and that will be delayed.
When you use `$(choose_item)`, you don't start `select` but a subprocess calling your function. In this case you will kill the subprocess, what works "without issues".
When you like the killed-without-delay behaviour of `$(choose_item)`, change your function:

```
choose_item () {
   (
   PS3="Choose an item in the preceding list: "
   select n in ${a[*]}; do
     echo "You choose $n"
     return 0
   done
   )
}
```

Now the `select` is called in a subprocess and you can you `choose_item`.